# What is a plain English explanation of Jenkins' OneOffExecutor?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a script that uses Jenkins REST API to get all current running builds. I can get a list of nodes and their executors information from `computer/api/json` in the format of:

```
{
    "computer": [
        {
            "displayName": "master",
            "executors": [...]
            "oneOffExecutors": [
                {
                    "currentExecutable": {<my_pipeline_job_info>}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "slave1",
            "executors": [
                {
                    "currentExecutable": null,
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "currentExecutable": null,
                    ...
                }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the pipeline definition groovy script, I restrict the job to run only on slave node:

```
node("slave_label") {...}
```

I noticed that, although they are actually running on the slave node, in the above JSON response, they are not showing up in the 'executors' section under each slave node. Instead, they are on `oneOffExecutors` on master node.

I couldn't find any good explanation of oneOffExecutors except one line in the class JavaDoc:

> Executor that's temporarily added to carry out tasks that doesn't
>   consume regular executors, like a matrix project parent build.

So what is oneOffExecutor exactly? Why my pipeline jobs are not running on regular executors on slave nodes?

Comment: See my (old answer below), however, I think what may also help is this: When jenkins starts your PipelineJob built, it runs ON the master (in a one-off) for the entire duration of the job. In fact ALL pipeline groovy runs in the master - not on the agent/node.  Execution can only run on executor(s) of a node once it reaches the node step, finds a suitable node and starts the execution there.

To make it more obtuse, one pipeline job can simultaneously run (via parallel) on MULTIPLE nodes, and multiple executors at once, or on **no** nodes at all.

Answer (score 0):

[OneOffExecutor](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012808951-Pipeline-Difference-between-flyweight-and-heavyweight-Executors), also called a *Flyweight Executor*, is a thread on your Jenkins master that tracks and coordinates a pipeline build.  While they are called *FlyWeights* they actually can cause a significant load on your master, for example, while your build on a slave is shipping logs back, the master has to receive those logs and write them.  When your job archives artifacts, they are shipped back to the master and written on the Master file system.  They are *Flyweight* in the sense that they may be idle doing nothing except waiting for the slave(s) to complete the task(s), and they take little memory to maintain.

In your example, **my_pipeline_job_info** may be waiting for a node (slave), may be ending, or may have JUST been dequeued and not yet doing anything, however all the time that job (or any pipeline job) is running, it will have a Flyweight executor on the master.

See also https://serverfault.com/a/981461/236229 for an explanation of how Jenkins shows One Off executors on the master.

By the way, slaves can have OneOffExecutors, too.
You can monitor what is running on the Master as "OneOffExecutors" as you have shown, but here is a more complete URL:

`https://YOUR.JENKINS.URL/computer/(master)/api/python?pretty=true&tree=oneOffExecutors[currentExecutable[fullDisplayName,result,id,url]]&depth=1`

But you can also substitute `(master)` with your actual **slave1** name to see OneOff Executors on other slaves.

Answer (score -1):

Executor of a slave should return something when it is not idle. Instead it shows up in the oneoffexecutor. I am facing the same problem. I want to identify which slaves are running what builds but i can't distinguish because executors of slave is empty

If you got any insight, please do share.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment. Use the comment feature to comment on existing posts instead.

Comment: I cannot use the comments feature at the moment because i don't have the points. I am stuck in the problem and only yuahao can assist me.
Can you leave this be for now. Thanks